# turtlebot runs into obstacles

Tags: navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im a very new to ROS. I have a turtlebot with a Kobuki base. Bot came with an Astra camera and I was able to use gmapping and save the map. I was able to run amcl to navigate the map. I have added a xv-11 lidar recently and used the wiki about adding a Lidar. I used the XV-11 driver. I am able to create and save the map using the xv-11 laser. But I am unable to navigate while avoiding obstacles. Turtlebot sees the obstacles via the xv-11 scan but it runs right into the obstacles. I have searched high and low and made some tweaks but nothing seemed to have help. Not sure why I'm doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction ?

### here is my costmap common file

```
max_obstacle_height: 0.60  # assume something like an arm is mounted on top of the robot
```

## Obstacle Cost Shaping (http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/inflation)

```
robot_radius: 0.14  # distance a circular robot should be clear of the obstacle (kobuki: 0.18) #changed-tkj

# footprint: [[x0, y0], [x1, y1], ... [xn, yn]]  # if the robot is not circular
footprint: [[0.20, 0.20], [-0.20, 0.20], [-0.20, -0.20], [0.20, -0.20]] #added-by-tkj

map_type: voxel

obstacle_layer:
  enabled:              true
  max_obstacle_height:  0.6
  origin_z:             0.0
  z_resolution:         0.2
  z_voxels:             2
  unknown_threshold:    15
  mark_threshold:       0
  combination_method:   1
  track_unknown_space:  true    #true needed for disabling global path planning through unknown space
  obstacle_range: 2.5
  raytrace_range: 3.0
  origin_z: 0.0
  z_resolution: 0.2
  z_voxels: 2
  publish_voxel_map: false
  observation_sources:  laser_scan bump
  laser_scan:
    data_type: LaserScan
    topic: scan
    sensor_frame: neato_laser
    marking: true
    clearing: true
    min_obstacle_height: 0.25
    max_obstacle_height: 0.35
  bump:
    data_type: PointCloud2
    topic: mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud
    marking: true
    clearing: false
    min_obstacle_height: 0.0
    max_obstacle_height: 0.15
  # for debugging only, let's you see the entire voxel grid

#cost_scaling_factor and inflation_radius were now moved to the inflation_layer ns
inflation_layer:
  enabled:              true
  cost_scaling_factor:  5.0  # exponential rate at which the obstacle cost drops off (default: 10)
  inflation_radius:     0.25  # max. distance from an obstacle at which costs are incurred for planning paths. #changed-tkj

static_layer:
  enabled:              true
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270997/turtlebot-runs-into-obstacles/) by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2017-09-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-15**:
I formatted the config files to make it easier to read. The easiest way to do that is to paste your config/source/etc. in the text box, highlight it, click the `101010` button.

**Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-09-15**:
Jayess - thanks for fixing the log file. Next time I will use the button.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-15**:
Have you gone through the [navigation tuning guide](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide)?

**Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-09-15**:
yes, to the best of my newb abilities.
Seems to be like the obstacles are not getting published in the costmap.

**Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-09-15**:
Is there a topic is need to make sure that needs to be published to troubleshoot this?

### **Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-09-15**:
ok my turtlebot seems to be behaving correct and avoiding obstacles now. I changed the line in costmap_common_params.yaml.
from

observation _sources: bump laser_scan

### to

obstacle_layer:
observation_sources: bump laser_scan

**Comment by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) on 2017-09-15**:
saw this on another question in this forum. I will try and find the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok my turtlebot seems to be behaving correct and avoiding obstacles now. I changed the line in `costmap_common_params.yaml`.
from

```
observation _sources: bump laser_scan
```

to

```
obstacle_layer: observation_sources: bump laser_scan
```

---

Originally posted by [tjadhav](https://answers.ros.org/users/31352/tjadhav/) with karma: 68 on 2017-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1